How slow are For, While, and recursion in LibreOffice Basic?
When the button is pressed, I want an infinite loop (For/While/Recursion or for + recursion, as the stack limits infinite recursion) to start, which will do something and then Wait 50 or any other specified time, as I want to be bound to the time.

' run loop work with recursion and for cycle
Sub loopWork
    Dim i as Integer
    i = 0
    Do while i <= 1000
        if stateMainTimer = 2 Then
            Exit Sub
        endif   
        loopWorkVoidRecursionWithFor()
        i=i+1
    Loop
    loopWork()
End Sub

' loop some cycle in recursion with for
Sub loopWorkVoidRecursionWithFor
    if stateMainTimer = 2 THEN
        Exit Sub
    else

    doWork()
    Dim dt As Double
    dt = Timer() - lastTimeOfTimers
    if dt > TimerFps THEN
        lastTimeOfTimers = Timer()
    else
        Wait (TimerFps - dt)
        lastTimeOfTimers = Timer()
    endif
    endif
End Sub

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' run loop work with recursion
Sub loopWorkRec
    loopWorkVoid()
End Sub

' loop some cycle in recursion
Sub loopWorkVoid
    if stateMainTimer = 2 THEN
        Exit Sub
    else

    doWork()
    Dim dt As Double
    dt = Timer() - lastTimeOfTimers
    if dt > TimerFps THEN
        lastTimeOfTimers = Timer()
        loopWorkVoid()
    else
        Wait (TimerFps - dt)
        lastTimeOfTimers = Timer()
        loopWorkVoid()
    endif
    endif
End Sub

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' run loop work with cycle while
Sub loopWork
    Dim i as Integer
    i = 0
    Do while i <= 1
        if stateMainTimer = 2 Then
            Exit Sub
        endif   
        doWork()        
    Loop
End Sub

' do this work value of cell A1 increment
Sub doWork
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + 1
End Sub

' stop job when click button stop job
Sub stopJob
stateMainTimer = 2
End Sub


'Range function for libre office like in office
Function Range(ByVal rngAddress As String) As Object
    ' Assuming you have a Calc document open
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object
    Dim oRange As Object

    ' Get the current document
    oDoc = ThisComponent

    ' Get the active sheet
    oSheet = oDoc.CurrentController.ActiveSheet

    ' Get the range based on the address
    Set oRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByName(rngAddress)

    ' Return the Range object
    Set Range = oRange
End Function

I've written this code as an example. You can create an empty LibreOffice document, create a button, and then attach one of the methods to run it.
I would like to know which of these is the fastest, and also how to create an infinite recursion (if possible, as recursion may be faster overall). I don't want to use third-party libraries or connect other programming languages. I also don't want to use Application.OnTime, as it's important to me that the code is only in LibreOffice Basic. Application.OnTime is not suitable because the macro runs in a different context, and I have to think about how to fill in global variables, which doesn't work for me. Yes. I'm doing this to have a so-called constant timer that is bound to time, or close to being time-bound.

Basic as a rule isn't the fastest language, Basic embedded in an app even less so.

Despite this, I can achieve calmly by setting TimerFps = 20-30, around ~25 iterations per second, which is sufficient for my task. The only thing is that I get this during recursion, but recursion is not infinite.

"I would like to know which of these is the fastest" -- what did you find when you tested the performance, and why don't your findings answer the question?  In other words -- what more are you asking for that you can't determine yourself with regards to "which is fastest"?

If you want to know which is fastest, write a benchmark to find out. Why are you expecting us to do it for you?

I'm not asking anyone to do this for me; I wanted to ask knowledgeable people who know which of these is faster. Regarding benchmarks, speed testing isn't just about measuring the time before and after performing an operation and finding the difference; it's a fairly deep topic. For example, in Java, frequently repeated functions are compiled for faster execution, and we can set a threshold before compilation. To understand this, it's not enough to simply get the time before and after the operations.

According to my tests, recursion is the fastest. In the case of loops, they seem to work a bit slower. However, recursion is limited by the stack, so I combined recursion with a loop, which made the execution slower but still acceptable. I want to confirm that this is the case and then think about how to make recursion potentially infinite.

Recursion will never be infinite, because stack space isn't infinite.  Unless your algorithm and language both support tail recursion.
